# Unable to locate element _ Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to locate HTML element with python selenium but I'm always getting the following message : Unable to locate element.

**Code I'm using : *browser.find_element_by_id("X14Edit")***

**HTML code is below :**

Thanks in Advance.
Meriem.

Comment: can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: It's not a webpage actually, it's not it is not accessible to public but I can share the HTML code

Comment: Please check if that element is inside iframe

Comment: Yes that's the case I can see the iframe in the HTML code

Comment: Can you show that iframe element HTML?

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the iframe before accessing that element.
I hope the iframe id is not dynamic.
In this case your code will be:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen341"))
browser.find_element_by_id("X14Edit")
```

If the iframe id is dynamic, but there is no more iframes there you can simply select it by tag name as following:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
browser.find_element_by_id("X14Edit")
```

Comment: Thank you I think in my case the iframe is dynamic in fact the id value changes, what shall I do in this case ??

Comment: Are there multiple iframes there?

Comment: No I found one iframe

Comment: See my updated answer. I can't see your web page so I can't verify it is the only iframe there.

Comment: Thank you , and if we have multiple iframes, how can we identify a specific one ?

Comment: First, if I answered your question please accept my answer. Second, if there are multiple iframes with dynamic locators... You have to locate them according to some other parent or child elements that are having fixed attributes etc